# Firefox add-on execute only in debugging state

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

I have developed an add-on to communicate with a smart card. I have used `winscard.dll` and its functions (such as Establishment, Connecting, Transmitting).

```
//less-privileged scope like jsp 

var element = document.createElement("MyExt1");
document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("SCardConnect", true,false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
var CardHandle = element.getAttribute("CardHandle");
alert(CardHandle);
```

and

```
//privileged scope which exist in my add-on

.
.
.
var MyExtension1 = {
    Connect : function(evt){
        ...
        evt.target.setAttribute("CardHandle", CH.toString());
        var doc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
        var AnswerEvt = doc.createElement("SCardConnect");
        doc.documentElement.appendChild(AnswerEvt);
        var event = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("ConnectEvent",true,false);
        AnswerEvt.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}    
.
.
.
document.addEventListener("SCardConnect", function(e){myExtension1.Connect(e);}, false, true);
```

After a small introduction, this is my problem:

When I install the add-on in Firefox and debug the code step by step through F10 it works fine, however if I want to run the external script without interruption (without debugging), it returns `null` when I get attributes.

This is an event-based approach to call an add-on function from an external script function. There is another approach that used `export function` which I get following problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450103/calling-a-firefox-add-on-function-from-an-external-javascript-file

Comment: you have some syntactical errors in you first part of the code, please fix them

Comment: @micnic thanks for your edition, I have corrected the syntactical errors.

Comment: I think the problem is due to event-based approach. Is there any alternative mechanism for calling add-on functions from external script without event?
Already I have tried `export function` in js-ctypes, however it did not work.
As I asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688218/calling-firefox-add-on-function-from-an-external-javascript.

Comment: If there is like an external program you can use `child_process`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process would this work?

Comment: dear @Noitidart , How can I use this require function or other ones in my jsp? I think require function in javascript is not defined.

Comment: Have you any idea about `export function` and especially my this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688218/calling-firefox-add-on-function-from-an-external-javascript

Comment: Also I realized that the speed of event-based method is too low and it is not applicable for my case :(

Comment: You can use require, the addon we made is jpm right, so you can use require in index.js. You cant use it in the ChromeWorker though. That link is taking me to deleted topic.

Comment: Excuse me, I had replaced that question with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450103/what-is-the-simple-and-fast-method-for-calling-a-function-of-firefox-add-on-in-c

Comment: I have found that this type of event-based approach is old and there is a new one called Custom Event in developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/…, however I did not understand how convert two above mentioned code!

Comment: @Noitidart I'm still discovering new things. In the less-privileged scope, if we put an `alert()` after dispatching command, it works properly. At first I think that it needs some delay, so I comment the `alert()` and put a delay after dispatching, but it is not worked by setting delay. What happen when I put an alert after dispatch function?

Comment: Also somewhere in Mozilla says that `initEvent` is depricated, however it used it in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages .

Comment: You are going to call a function which has already been implemented in your firefox add-on from a jsp page, aren't you?

Comment: @Hamed yes I want to do what exactly you said, and I only found an event-based approach which has many problems like slowness.

Comment: Please place two buttons on your jsp page, and move 'var CardHandle = element.getAttribute("CardHandle");' to the second button. Then let me know the result.

Comment: Yessssss, its work without inserting alert after dispatching :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to move 'var CardHandle = element.getAttribute("CardHandle");' into a new function and check if its value has been valid or not in specified intervals.

```
var varTimer = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var CardHandle = element.getAttribute("CardHandle");
    if(CardHandle is valid) stopTimer();
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(varTimer);
}
```